# Eclipse:Unable to set up sdk path in preference

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, path

I am facing some problem Eclipse.
When i open the eclipse it shows a message

> This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.0.0 or
>   above Current version is 16.0.xxxxxxxxxxxx Please update to latest ADT
>   version

I tried to open the sdk manager in eclipse it is showing that

> Location of Android SDK has not been set up in Preference

Previously i setup everything and i was running apps in eclipse.Don't know suddenly what happened.

I checked preference ,there sdk path is given but there its showing that

> This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.0.0 or
>   above.  Current version is 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534.  Please update
>   ADT to the latest version.

I have checked the sdk path from windows explorer and updated it to latest 22.o.after that I restarted the Eclipse but then  also same messages are showing in eclipse.Now i am unable to use it .Can anyone help?

Also I have seen somewhere that tools folder may be missing.But my case it is there.
I am using Eclipse Indigo,windows 7.

Comment: In eclipse, go to "Help"-> "Check for updtade" and update the ADT plugin.

Comment: thnks. i am updating it.

Comment: Is it OK? give me a feedback please.

Comment: @Jarvis ya it worked.thnks.if u separately post the soln ill accept it answer

Comment: @ ok good! glad it worked! I have done what you said. THANKS! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update your android sdk with the sdk manager, try each time to update the ADT eclipse plugin.
So, in eclipse, go to "Help"-> "Check for updtade" and update the ADT plugin.

Answer (score 1):

u can update ADT plung v22 from android dev guide and install use below steps:

1. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
2. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
3. In the Add Repository dialog, click Archive.
4. Select the downloaded ADT-22.0.0.zip file and click OK.
5. Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name and click OK.
6. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
7. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
   Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
   If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.

When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

Plase download latest ADT from belwo link...

"http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html "

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

in the eclipse IDE click File > Switch Workspace > Other . Then go to following folder : .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.prefs

open file com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.prefs using notepad.
here is my file:

```html
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.fixLegacyEditors=1
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.sdk=C\:\\Users\\PICARY\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.xmlEditor=true
eclipse.preferences.version=1
```

in line com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.sdk=........
change that line to your path sdk installation like com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.sdk=C:\Users\computer account name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

and then restart the eclipse